# Фиксированный фон

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: `<body>` выходит за пределы `<footer>`.

```
CSS:
body {
background-image: url(/image/background.png);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 110%;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px;
font-size: 9pt;
font-family: tahoma;
color: #222222;}
HTML:
<body>
<div class="header>...</div>
<div class="text">....</div>
<footer>....</footer>
</body>
```

При расширении экрана больше 600 по высоте `<body>` продолжает показывать свой фон за пределами `<footer>....</footer>`.

Помогите исправить данную проблему. Спасибо.

Comment: >background-size: cover; 

или 

>background-size: contain;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> background-size: 110%; конечно будет продолжаться=)

```
background:url(myimg.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
```

width: 100%;
height: 100%;